# Android Studio: Java or XML issue?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to learn how to code Android apps, and have been working through the `Big Nerd Ranch` Android book.  I have Java experience but no XML / mobile, and I've run into an issue - but I'm not sure if the problem is in the Java or the XML.

I have debugged and double-checked, My code matches the example code exactly - but the example code produces the correct results. Mine is correct with a twist.

Here's the problem.  The screen `onCreate` is supposed to look like this:

- crime title (TextView)                CheckBox

  crime date  (TextView)

  crime title (TextView)                CheckBox

  crime date  (TextView)

  crime title (TextView)                CheckBox

  crime date  (TextView)

  crime title (TextView)                CheckBox

  crime date  (TextView)

(...)

But here's what I get:

- crime title (TextView)                CheckBox

  crime date  (TextView)

(...)

[scroll down to next screen]

(...)

- crime title (TextView)                CheckBox

  crime date  (TextView)

So, all the correct data is there, but the items from the List are on different screens.  I have to scroll down for each "crime".  The correct way should be a list on the screen that continues as you scroll all the way down to the 100th "crime".

I'm not sure if this is a Java issue or an XML issue.  I am using a `RelativeLayout` in the XML, with a `CheckBox` and two `TextView`s as the children.  I know how to debug the Java, but this has produced no result that I can see as useful.

Does anyone have any insights or help they can offer regarding where the issue lies?

Thanks for the advice!

`ViewHolder` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/list_item_crime_solved_check_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="4dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_crime_title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/list_item_crime_solved_check_box"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="4dp"
        tools:text="Crime Title"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_crime_date_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/list_item_crime_solved_check_box"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_item_crime_title_text_view"
        android:padding="4dp"
        tools:text="Crime Date"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`CrimeHolder` source code:

```
private class CrimeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView mTitleTextView;
    private TextView mDateTextView;
    private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;

    private Crime mCrime;

    public CrimeHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTitleTextView = (TextView)
                itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_crime_title_text_view);
        mDateTextView = (TextView)
                itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_crime_date_text_view);
        mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox)
                itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_crime_solved_check_box);
    }

    public void bindCrime(Crime crime) {
        mCrime = crime;
        mTitleTextView.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
        mDateTextView.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
        mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mCrime.isSolved());
    }
}
```

`CrimeAdapter` source code:

```
private class CrimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CrimeHolder> {
    private List<Crime> mCrimes;

    public CrimeAdapter(List<Crime> crimes) {
        mCrimes = crimes;
    }

    @Override
    public CrimeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime,
                        parent, false);
        return new CrimeHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CrimeHolder holder, int position) {
        Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
        holder.bindCrime(crime);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCrimes.size();
    }
}
```

`Activity` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

`SingleFragmentActivity` source code:

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        if(fragment == null) {
            fragment = createFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you attach your xml file?

Comment: If i understand correctly your layout is stretched out, you can try and set parent layout height to: android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: Please post your layout xml.

Comment: I have added the XML... thanks again.

Comment: instead of writing how it should look like, post a picture rather? :O

Comment: where is your scroll view? You're probably missing it.

Comment: I'd like to post a picture, but my StackOverflow "level" isn't high enough yet... and, I wasn't sure about ScrollView... It makes sense to me, but it was not included in the provided example in the book...

Comment: Please post Your activity layout and code. I suppose You haven't properly configured RecyclerView in the activity.

Comment: Your viewholder's `layout_height` is `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`

Comment: @tommus not sure if that is what you are asking for... but posted...

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Your suggestion may have been the answer.  Thank you.  It looks like wrap_content in the height was one of, if not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I wanted to point out that ***@EpicPandaForce*** and ***@tommus*** pointed me in the right direction.  I tweaked the layout_height in the RecyclerView, and the layout_height in the RelativeLayout, and the issue appears to be fixed.

Went from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`.

Thanks everyone.